# Can I create a JFrame with list of images?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I would like to create a JFrame in Java with a list of images downloaded from the web. I would place them in the JFrame below to each other and to the side of the image a text, how can I do it?

What I did:

```
    Image image = null;
    ArrayList<JLabel> lb = new ArrayList<JLabel>(); // list of images 

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300, 300);

    lb.add(...);

    //...

    frame.add(lb);

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You'll need to iterate over the labels and add them to the frame one by one.

Comment: If you want them to be side by side then http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html might interest you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **GridLayout**

```
ArrayList<JLabel> lb=new ArrayList<JLabel>(); //list of images

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,columns));//In your case (lb.size,2)
frame.setSize(300, 300);

//Now You need to Iterate through the List.

for(JLabel label:lb){
  frame.add(lb);  //Adding each image to the Frame
  frame.add(textLabel); //This is the text you want in side of image
 }

frame.setVisible(true);
```

As suggested by  @Jean-François Savard , Below is an example of what you will get

[image: Grid Layout]